# cURL Post Header In PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I try to get my access token in Twitter API:
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

I'm use cURL in PHP, I did not get a result!

My code:

```
$consumer_key       =   "XXXXXXXX";
$consumer_secret    =   "XXXXXXXX";

$base64             =   base64_encode($consumer_key.':'.$consumer_secret);

$data = array("grant_type" => "client_credentials");

$header = array(
                "Authorization"     =>  "Basic $base64",
                "Content-Type"      =>  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                "Accept-Encoding"   =>  "gzip",
            );

$curlObj = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt ($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($curlObj);
$json = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($curlObj);

print_r($json);
```

Where is the problem?!

Comment: you're just assuming success. curl_exec returns boolean false on failure. `if ($response === false) { die(curl_error($curlObj)); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the headers incorrectly. The header array is not in key-value pair. It is just a simple array. Like below:

```
$header = array(
    "Authorization: Basic $base64",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip",
);
```

And for the post fields use the function `http_build_query` over the `$data`.

```
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```